# How resolving Kotlin functions/properties with the same name work?

Tags: kotlin, language-design

The following statement compiles and prints `"fun: called"`:

```
fun main(vararg args: String) {
    fun toCall(arg: String) = println("fun: $arg")
    val toCall = fun(arg: String) = println("val: $arg")
    toCall("called")
}
```

Note: the same problem would arise if they were top level declarations or inside a class, this is just the simplest repro with local function/variable.

**Looking for clarification on why this compiles in the first place?**
**What rule comes into play that picks the function over the property?**

Note: it's possible to call the `val` one through:

- `(toCall)("called")`
- `toCall.invoke("called")`

Comment: Related: https://github.com/angryziber/kotlin-puzzlers/pull/42

Comment: Related: https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C0922A726/p1533980106000043

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This document regarding name resolution](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/NameResolution.adoc) contains details about it.

I will just quote some passages out of it specifically dealing with your problem. It contains several other interesting things as well, but I think I would end up copying everything here then ;-) If you are interested, I can only recommend you to read it completely.

Summarizing, the compiler divides the functions (member/extension/member extension)/properties into groups and decides which one to call first... The properties are put in the group of the `invoke`-functions and in the following passage you already see why the function was taken before your `val`:

> The property is considered together with the `invoke` function. Groups of properties with `invoke` functions are mixed with groups of regular functions, in a sense that a group of properties can have higher priority than a group of functions and vice versa. However, functions and properties can’t go in one group: **the function always surpasses the property of the same category**. Both the property and the `invoke` function determine the priority of the group: we compare the priority of the property and of the `invoke` function and the "lowest" one becomes the group priority.

That's why the function was considered first here and the property later. As soon as you specified `invoke` it was clear that it can only be the property as the function itself has no visible `invoke` (lets not go down the byte code now ;-)). Now `(toCall)` behaves similarly. Here it is clear, that `toCall` can only be the property. It isn't possible to call `(toCall)` with the function (compile errors: function invocation expected / the function `invoke` is not found).

The linked document also contains a sample with a member property function followed by this statement, which basically also confirms the previous regarding local functions:

> Note that there is no member function named foo, but if it was present, it would be put into a separate group with the highest priority.